# link with variables from mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a difficult time whit this.

sql(php file, not to be viewed,`ocene_dijaka_pri_predmetu.php`):

```
$stavek="SELECT ocena,id_o 
           FROM ocena 
           INNER JOIN predmet as p on p.id_p=ocena.id_p 
           INNER JOIN tip_ocene as tip on tip.id_tip=ocena.id_tip
           INNER JOIN dijak as d on d.id_dijak=ocena.id_dijak
           WHERE ime='$ime' AND priimek='$priimek' AND ime_predmeta='$predmet' ;"; // AND datum='$datum'
  $rezultat=  mysql_query($stavek);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rezultat))
  {

      $tab[$stevc]=$row['ocena'];
      $tab2[$stevc]=$row['id_o'];
            $stevc++;
}
```

later on...

```
   $_SESSION['ocena']=$tab;
   $_SESSION['id_ocene']=$tab2;
```

This goes to prva.php:

```
<?php

     if(isset($_SESSION['ocena']))
         {
         if($_SESSION['ocena']!="")
         {
             foreach($_SESSION['ocena'] as $ocena)
             {
                 foreach ($_SESSION['id_ocene'] as $id)
                 {
                 echo '<a href=podrobnosti.php?id_ocene='."$id".'.'>''."$ocena".'</a>';
                  }
              }
             }
             else
         {
             echo "Butast si!";
         }
         }
         else{echo 'Ocene';}

         ?>
```

Now i just doesn't work.. `$id`'s are all time same for all $ocena.

I want `<a href=podorbnosti.php?id_ocene=$id>$ocena</a>` to show each $id for each $ocena...

example: in my db I have `id_o=1` and `ocena=5`.
I want href to pass that id for each ocean. so `ocena=4` has `id_o=2` and $id in a href will be 2.

I thought to pass whole `mysql_fetch_array`, but I don't know how.

Comment: I'm not sure what output you want. If you have a row with id_o=1 and ocena=5, and a row with id_o=2 and ocena=6, do you want 2 links? Ex: one link with `id_ocene=1 and ocena=5`, and another link with `id_ocene=2 and ocena=6` Or 4 links, ? Ex: `id_ocene=1 and ocena=5`, `id_ocene=2 and ocena=5`, `id_ocene=1 and ocena=6`, `id_ocene=2 and ocena=6` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with a bit cleaner code:

```
 $tab = array();
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rezultat))
 {
      $tab[] = $row;
 }
```

Then assign to session variable as :
     $_SESSION['ocena'] = $tab;

Now, prva.php

```
<?php
     if (isset($_SESSION['ocena'])) {

         foreach($_SESSION['ocena'] as $ocena) {
                echo '<a href=podrobnosti.php?id_ocene='.$ocena['id_o'].'>'.$ocena['ocena'].'</a>'." ";
         }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works. Just fixed some quotation marks and it works. Thank you for your time!